# Caffe bvlc_googlenet minimum accepted dimensions

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, caffe, pycaffe

What is the minimum image input size accepted by `bvlc_googlenet` model implemented by `Caffe`?

I'm using **50 x 50** images with **crop_size = 36**, where i get the following error when running the solver:

```
caffe::Blob<>::Reshape() - Floating point exception
```

I have to resize my images to **256 x 256** (default input size of the bvlc_googlenet model) with **crop_size = 224** to avoid the error.

Do this model only accept its default sizes or i have to hack around a bit to make it happen?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of trying to fix the problem, i figured out why i was facing it.
**GoogleNet** accepts **224*224** images as input by default, so because it is so deep and after a set of convolution and pooling layers, using a **50*50** images (or **36*36** after crop) will lead into a very small sized output, after passing the input into some layers, smaller than the **kernel size** of the next layer. This will cause a Reshape exception similar to the one i faced here.

**Solution:**

1. Although its not preferred to edit the **kernel_size** param of the layer causing the exception (to keep working up to the NN's specifications), this will fix the problem, Where you could choose a smaller kernel size and then test the results until it works.
2. Follows the default **GoogleNet**'s specifications by resizing your input images into **254*254** (*keeping crop size to 224*) or directly changing it to **224*224** and removing the **crop_size** param.